# Flutter Firestore _MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatform, DocumentSnapshot> is not a subtype of Stream<QuerySnapshot>

Tags: flutter, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

after hours of struggling and browsing i need your help.

I'm on a flutter projet with firestore implemented. I'm on mvvm architecture using riverpod.

My firestore service has this code :

```
CollectionReference getCollection(String collection) =>
      _firestore.collection(collection);

  getCurrentCustomer() {
    String uid = _auth.currentUser.uid;
    print('current customer id is : $uid');
    var customerStream = getCollection('customer')
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
    print('customerStream is a $customerStream');
    return customerStream;
  }
```

And i access this FirestoreService with this provider :

```
final firestoreProvider = Provider<FirestoreService>((ref) {
  return FirestoreService(
    ref.read(authentificationServiceProvider),
  );
});
```

On my CustomerProfileViewModel i got this :

```
final customerProfileViewModelProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<CustomerProfileViewModel>((ref) {
  return CustomerProfileViewModel(
    ref.read(authentificationServiceProvider),
    ref.read(navigationServiceProvider),
    ref.read(firestoreProvider),
  );
});

class CustomerProfileViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final AuthentificationService _auth;
  final NavigationService _navigationService;
  final FirestoreService _firestore;

  CustomerProfileViewModel(
      this._auth, this._navigationService, this._firestore);


  getCurrentCustomerInfo() {
    Stream customerStream = _firestore.getCurrentCustomer();
    print('customer Stream sur le model est $customerStream');
    return customerStream;
  }

  updateCurrentUserInfo({String dataField, dataValue}) {
    _firestore.updateCurrentCustomerInfo(dataField, dataValue);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And finally, in my CustomerProfileView which is a ConsumerWidget i call my model like this :

```
var model = watch(customerProfileViewModelProvider);
var stream = model.getCurrentCustomerInfo();
```

And got my StreamBuilder setup like this

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: stream,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot
    )
```

Then i get this error :

```
I/flutter ( 2609): current customer id is : 9tZTfddurwQRsSuGnH7pkPvmvvF2
I/flutter ( 2609): customerStream is a Instance of '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatform, DocumentSnapshot>'
I/flutter ( 2609): customer Stream sur le model est Instance of '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatform, DocumentSnapshot>'
I/flutter ( 2609): stream view est Instance of '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatform, DocumentSnapshot>'

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building CustomerProfileView(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState#b4319):
type '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatform, DocumentSnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CustomerProfileView file:///Users/Alex/AndroidStudioProjects/clickncollect/lib/ui/views/home/home_viewmodel.dart:35:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      CustomerProfileView.build (package:clickncollect_app/ui/views/customer/customer_profile/customer_profile_view.dart:40:25)
#1      _ConsumerState.build (package:flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:300:35)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4627:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

It works all same work with a Future, querying with collection('customers').doc(uid).get() and build it with a FutureBuilder.

Please help me, I've never seen this MapStream type and neither the internet did (after hours of searching).

Thanks for reading !

Comment: The `getCurrentCustomer` function returns a `_MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatform, DocumentSnapshot>` object  and the `StreamBuilder` : stream expects an `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` object. You can find [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/reading-lists-from-firestore-using-streambuilder-in-flutter-eda590f461ed) an example `stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Videos').snapshots()`

Comment: Thanks for you response. 
I'm totally aware of that, the things is why my function getCurrentCustomer return that _MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatfome, DocumentSnapchot> instead of the Stream<QuerySnapshot>. It should return that last type.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that asking for a stream from a DocumentReference is impossible.
So i've filtered my CollectionReference snapshots with a where condition.
I've tried first :

```
getCurrentCustomerInfo() {
    var uid = _auth.currentUser.uid;
  
    Stream customerStream = _firestore
        .getCollection('customers')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots();
    print('customer Stream on the model is ${customerStream}');
    return customerStream;
  }
```

But it didn't work.
Then i found that `'id'` in the where condition were the probleme and i found this :

```
getCurrentCustomerInfo() {
    var uid = _auth.currentUser.uid;
    
    Stream customerStream = _firestore
        .getCollection('customers')
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots();
    print('customer Stream on the model is ${customerStream}');
    return customerStream;
  }
```

Then on the view you juste have to fetch the first element with this

`var customer = snapshot.data.docs.first.data();`

And you get the data form the snapshot from the stream. So it updates !

Comment: Hi Alexandre Savinien, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Jose, sadly but it's understandable i can't vote for my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot //Your stream is of type <DocumentSnapshot> not <QuerySnapshot>
    // change it like this
)
```

Why? in the function `getCurrentCostumer()` you return

```
var customerStream = getCollection('customer').doc(uid)
  .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
```

if you change var to `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` the editor will warn you that this is not the type the stream return, QuerySnapshot is a class that extends DocumentSnapshot, not the other way around, which is used when you use query like `where`, `limitAt`, `endsAt`, etc, so it isn't Dart who is misunderstanding the type, but you are casting it to a different type that it is

What is this `_MapStream<DocumentSnapshotPlatfom, DocumentSnapshot>` instead of the Stream you ask?

snapshot use the function [map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html) `Stream.map()` to transform each element to a new stream event, the implementation use this _MapStream<T, S>(this, convert) so it transforms the event T to S, in this case `DocumentSnapshotPlatfom` to `DocumentSnapshot`, this way you should now that the stream returned will be of type `DocumentSnapshot`

Comment: Hello and thank your for your answer !
I started with simple querying  with get() and future, that DocumentSnapshot type come from that. 
Then i wanted to try with a stream and forgot to change it to QuerySnapshot. 
Now that you point it i feel a bit bad about the time i spent on it ... 

By the way, huge thanks for your explanation about _MapStream, i couldn't find any pertinent information about it.